# Hadoop mover is too slow

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm using Hadoop Mover to tranfer some blocks.
But It's too slow.
Our cluster has network about 10 GBit/sec, but mover uses only 600-700 Mbit/sec.
Also I tried to "hack" and find a way to start 5 Movers simultaneously - but it doesn't help also: It's seems like 700Mbit/s is a limit.
Maybe there are some configuration limitations (e.g. on NameNode)?

Start parameters for Mover:

```
   -Ddfs.balancer.movedWinWidth=54000000 \
   -Ddfs.balancer.moverThreads=10000 \
   -Ddfs.datanode.balance.max.concurrent.moves=1000 \
   -Ddfs.balancer.dispatcherThreads=2000 \
   -Ddfs.datanode.balance.bandwidthPerSec=1000000000 \
   -Ddfs.balancer.max-size-to-move=10737418240 \
```

Comment: Not sure if it's risky, but what would happen if you double all the numbers in the presented config? Also is the network doing anything else? And are you able to utilize the full bandwidth with other tasks?

Comment: Nothing happends, when I increase this numbers. And yes, some times network utilization peeks up to 5+ GBits during other tasks

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this article](http://people.apache.org/%7Eliuml07/2017/07/07/My-HDFS-mover-is-slow/) it is a known issue for older Hadoop versions.

If you are able to use a recent distribution (e.g. HDP 2.6.5 or 3.1) you should be able to avoid the problem.

If that is not possible/not enough, consider reviewing the article for additional hints.

Comment: Thanks for article, but I have 2.7.6 HDP and your patch is already included in our build... You mention logs and metrics of NN. Should you share , where to look there for figuring out issue with mover?